# 1600*900 resolution in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I have a sync master lcd screen 20".
My graphics card is ՝9300gs nvidia՝
my motherboard is ՝gigabyte G31M՝
I can't find 1600*900 resolution in `Ubuntu 11.10` after fresh installation.
What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

`xrandr` shows this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the output of the "xrandr" command?  It might also be useful to know exactly what model screen you're using and what its native resolution is.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the information from the monitor is not being read correctly.

You can manually add modeline information to the monitor section. example belowModeline

```
Section "Monitor"
  Modeline "1600x900_60.00" 119.00 1600 1696 1864 2128 900 901 904 932 -HSync +Vsync
EndSection
```

Add the line above and you should then be able to select that resolution.

The xorg file should be located in:

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Comment: can you help by using teamviewer

Comment: I have not used teamviewer before... but I could try to learn it or help you via IRC. If you have IRC you can find me in #ubuntu-us-ny on freenode.